# telegram-bot-api/v5 SetWebhook function undefined

Tags: go

In the official documentation, there is the following example code to build tg bot with webhook:

```
func main() {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("MyAwesomeBotToken")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true

    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

    wh, _ := tgbotapi.NewWebhookWithCert("https://www.google.com:8443/"+bot.Token, "cert.pem")

    _, err = bot.SetWebhook(wh)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    info, err := bot.GetWebhookInfo()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if info.LastErrorDate != 0 {
        log.Printf("Telegram callback failed: %s", info.LastErrorMessage)
    }

    updates := bot.ListenForWebhook("/" + bot.Token)
    go http.ListenAndServeTLS("0.0.0.0:8443", "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil)

    for update := range updates {
        log.Printf("%+v\n", update)
    }
}
```

I'm following this example but get problem of Using bot.SetWebhook(wh)
it shows that

```
bot.SetWebhhook() undefined (type *tgbotapi.BotAPI has no field or method SetWebhook)
```

Is this package version problem or env setting problem? or something else?

I don't know how to slove this and come here asking for help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

the example you provided is old and there is no longer a `SetWebhhook` method. first install the package (install the latest if you did not):

```
go get -u github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5
```

and here is a working example including webhooks:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5"
)

func main() {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("MyAwesomeBotToken")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true

    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

    wh, _ := tgbotapi.NewWebhookWithCert("https://www.example.com:8443/"+bot.Token, "cert.pem")

    _, err = bot.Request(wh)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    info, err := bot.GetWebhookInfo()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if info.LastErrorDate != 0 {
        log.Printf("Telegram callback failed: %s", info.LastErrorMessage)
    }

    updates := bot.ListenForWebhook("/" + bot.Token)
    go http.ListenAndServeTLS("0.0.0.0:8443", "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil)

    for update := range updates {
        log.Printf("%+v\n", update)
    }
}
```